# ExtJS Application launch on demand - not page load

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a bundle of older ExtJs components that drive the UI, store management, and application logic in something that prior to the world of MVC I'd have called an application. I'm in the process of rewriting it, and wanted to take advantage of ExtJS MVC if possible.

The one thing that makes this unique from the tons of guides I'd otherwise be working from is that my Ext app doesn't own the whole page - instead of a full page viewport onready I have a modal Ext.window.Window that runs **on an event from other non-ext javascript on the page.**

I'd like to migrate this into a coherent ext application if possible, but as they seem to only properly launch when ext is ready I'm questioning if this is the right tool for the job.

My leading idea right now is to initialize the application on page load, but not actually render any views - exposing a static method on the app the external js can call to render and start my app's lifecycle on demand. Is this a good idea? Is there a better option I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a very good idea. I have written an example of [simple login system](http://extjs.eu/examples/#simple-login-system) where the application is not actually started before the user logs-in.

It is very similar to your way in that that there is a method you call to actually start the app.